# Installing scikit-learn 0.15 (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently using scikit-learn 0.14.1, which I installed using pip.  I'm running Python version 2.7.6 (64 bit), using Canopy Enthought as my IDE. My operating system is OSX 10.9.2

Currently, I am trying to install scikit-learn 0.15. I cloned the repository into my home directory, cd'ed into it, and typed 'python setup.py install' into the command line.

I got an error saying:

`error: could not delete '/Users/*****/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py': Permission denied`

Anyone have any advice on how I should go about installing scikit-learn 0.15? Should I have cloned the directory into `/Users/*****/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` ?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I did that, and while it appears to have upgraded to the proper version, I can't seem to import a bunch of packages.  

For example, 'from sklearn.svm import SVC' returns the following error: 'cannot import name inplace_column_scale'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way of installing many python packages, amongst which scikit-learn, without needing root priviledges is to install it locally

```
python setup.py install --user
```

which will write information to `~/.local`.

A second option is

```
python setup.py develop
```

which will compile in place and place a symbolic link in `/Users/*****/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. You may have to `sudo` and you may have to delete the old `sklearn`.

A third, more explicit way of doing this is to place the symbolic link yourself, which will require surgical, but very localized use of `sudo` for placing the link and removing the old scikit learn.

Assuming you cloned into `~/scikit-learn/`

```
cd ~/scikit-learn
make in
cd /Users/*****/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
sudo mv sklearn sklearn_
sudo ln -s ~/scikit-learn/sklearn sklearn
```

More detailed information on the website about [installing in general](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) and [installing the bleeding edge](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/index.html#git-repo)

Comment: where of course you can also opt to entirely remove the old sklearn by replacing the `mv` command with `sudo rm sklearn -rf`

Comment: I did the first two things you suggested and it totally worked. To avoid having packages scattered everywhere, I then moved the sklearn folder from the cloned repository into site-packages/, and deleted the .egg link file. Everything seems to be working fine. Is this kosher?

Comment: The `--user` installation should work wihtout having to copy anything. Essentially, what you seem to have done is build scikit-learn and then move the whole thing to `site-packages`, which is not the orthodox way of doing things, but if it works (check the version of the imported sklearn for starters) it works. However, any subsequent updates will all have to be done this way. A simple symbolic link to the git repo would have made it possible to update continuously without needing to copy each time.

Comment: Thanks, eickenberg.  I think I probably should have just cloned the repo into site-packages, and performed the --user installation in the site-packages directory. I just didn't want the cloned repo to be sitting in my home directory.